# German Special character not working in WordPress Schema

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, seo, schema

I am using the following filter to add some more Schema related information to my product.
But for some German character , it is converted to Numeric code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_structured_data_product', 'filter__woocommerce_structured_data_product', 20, 2 );
function filter__woocommerce_structured_data_product( $schema, $product ) {

global $post;

$shipping_val = utf8_decode( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pro_shipping', true ) ); 
// Not working : CHF 10.–
$colour_val = utf8_decode( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pro_color', true ) );
// Not working : Aussen: rosa und blau (metallisch), Bordüre: grün, Innen: lila

$schema['shipping'] = array(
    '@type'  => 'Shipping',
    'name'   => $shipping_val ,
);

  $schema['colour'] = array(
    '@type'  => 'Colour',
    'name'   => $colour_val ,
  );

  return $schema;

}
```

I have added comment , in that form actual data are stored in custom fields.
and I have added screen-shot , which convert actual data in numeric form

[image]

How do I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you've run `utf8_decode` function on those values, but you could use `iconv` function to convert them back to `utf8`.

So when you run `utf8_decode` it will convert your values to `ISO-8859-1` characters.

> utf8_decode: Converts a string with ISO-8859-1 characters encoded with UTF-8 to single-byte ISO-8859-1

We could use `ISO-8859-1` in `iconv` function.

> [`iconv`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

For example, if you run the following code:

```php
$german_word = "Bordüre: grün";

$utf8__decode_german_word = utf8_decode($german_word);

$utf8_german_word_main = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "utf-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $utf8__decode_german_word);

echo $german_word . "<br>";

echo $utf8__decode_german_word . "<br>";

echo $utf8_german_word_main . "<br>";
```

Which will output this:

```
// $german_word result
Bordüre: grün

// $utf8__decode_german_word result
Bord�re: gr�n

// $utf8_german_word_main result
Bordüre: grün
```

[image]

---

So your entire code would be something like this:

```php
add_filter("woocommerce_structured_data_product", "filter__woocommerce_structured_data_product", 20, 2);

function filter__woocommerce_structured_data_product($schema, $product)
{

    global $post;

    $shipping_val = utf8_decode(get_post_meta($post->ID, "pro_shipping", true));
    $colour_val = utf8_decode(get_post_meta($post->ID, "pro_color", true));


    $schema["shipping"] = array(
        "@type"  => "Shipping",
        "name"   => iconv("ISO-8859-1", "utf-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $shipping_val),
    );

    $schema["colour"] = array(
        "@type"  => "Colour",
        "name"   => iconv("ISO-8859-1", "utf-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $colour_val),
    );

    return $schema;
}
```

Let me know if you could get it to work.

Comment: Nice solution...

Comment: I tried your solution , but not working.
I used this function `utf8_decode` , that's why on Front-end it is showing exact characters like  ä . ü and ö 

But when I CTRL + U , to check schema , it is converting this character to some Numeric code.

Comment: For now , I have replaced characters like this :  ä = ae , ü = ue , ö = oe